# SELECT with multiple JOINs FROM multiple tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a timetable editor on a web page and I need to select TIMETABLE by using CLASS ID and by all users which are in that class by USER.CLASS ID = CLASS ID and from that users get GROUPs which have GROUP ID and GET ALL TIMETABLES with GROUP ID. Sorry for my explaining knowledge.

user is linked to class by cid.
userGroup is just uid and gid.
timetable has both cid and gid. When first is null second is given.

I've tried code below, and many combinations of all the JOINs which I can't seem to get working

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `timetable`.*,
    `group`.name AS groupName,
    `class`.name AS className
FROM
    `timetable`,
    `user`,
    `userGroup`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `group` ON `userGroup`.gid = `group`.gid
LEFT OUTER JOIN `class` ON `class`.cid = '1'
WHERE
    `user`.cid = 1 AND `userGroup`.uid = `user`.uid AND(
        `timetable`.gid = `group`.gid OR `timetable`.cid = '1'
    )
```

I expected output with 3 timetables. 1 from the class and 2 from different groups which are connected to users which are connected by class. I also wanted names which one is from GROUP and one from CLASS by respected ids i.e (gid, cid). Is there even way to get NULL on the className if cid is null?

Comment: An example of sample data and expected output goes a long ways towards explaining the specification. Also note that the old-school comma syntax for join operation has lower precedence than the newer JOIN syntax. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html  The takeaway there is: do not mix comma syntax join with JOIN keyword in the same SELECT; even if you know what you are doing there, it just confuses the heck out of anyone that would want to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed suggestion by @spencer7593 by using only "new-syntax" JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `timetable`.*,
    `group`.name AS groupName,
    `class`.name AS className
FROM
    `timetable` 
JOIN `user` ON `user`.cid = 1
JOIN `userGroup` ON `userGroup`.uid = `user`.uid
LEFT JOIN `group` ON `userGroup`.gid = `group`.gid AND `timetable`.cid IS null
LEFT JOIN `class` ON `class`.cid = '1' AND `timetable`.gid IS null
WHERE
    `timetable`.gid = `userGroup`.gid OR `timetable`.cid = '1'
```